# How can i integrate my html in to typo3 CMS?

Tags: html, typo3, integration

I have HTML of my website. And they have many functionalities and modules. How can I convert in typo3? My content area has many elements so how can I manage as we manage in WordPress?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] pleasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get used to the concepts of `Fluid Templates`. There is no general recipe for this.

In Fluid we have Template files, Layout files and Partial files. You have to split up your HTML page accordingly.

A problem will be to deal with the content elements. You probably will have to develop `custom content elements` to produce the same HTML code like Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. For some functionality best practice is writing a extension. For special layout elements [Create Custom Content Elements](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#adding-your-own-content-elements)